# How to install git-filter-repo?

Tags: package-management, git

I want to install `git-filter-repo` which is in https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+package/git-filter-repo

When I want to install it I get

```
$ sudo apt install git-filter-repo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package git-filter-repo
```

my system is:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64 
Host: VMware Virtual Platform None 
Kernel: 5.4.0-122-generic 
Uptime: 21 days, 16 hours, 26 mins 
Packages: 2342 (dpkg), 5 (snap) 
Shell: zsh 5.8 
Resolution: preferred 
Terminal: /dev/pts/0 
CPU: Intel Xeon Gold 6154 (6) @ 2.992GHz 
GPU: 00:0f.0 VMware SVGA II Adapter 
Memory: 5309MiB / 16008MiB
```

Comment: The package is only available for 21.10 and newer. Even the link you have is for 22.04.

Comment: see https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo#how-do-i-install-it